# Why are elements in my list being turned into None?

Tags: python

I am trying to take the items in a list, add them all up, and then put them in a 2d list. 
This is my code, in which I attempt to iterate through the list twice:

```
l = [1,3,5,7,9]
m = [l,l]
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if i != j:
            summ = l[i] + l[j]
             m[0][i] = summ
             m[1][j] = summ
print(m)
```

Whenever I run this, it gets stuck on the line "summ = l[i] + l[j]", saying that a NoneType object and an int cannot be added together, even though there are no NoneType objects in my list. I then edited the code to print what was in the lists if there was a problem:

```
l = [1,3,5,7,9]
m = [l,l]
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if i != j:
            if l[i] == None:
               print(i)
               print(l[i])
               print(l)
               break
            if l[j] == None:
               print(l)
               print(j)
               print(l[j])
               break
            summ = l[i] + l[j]
             m[0][i] = summ
             m[1][j] = summ
print(m)
```

This was the output:

```
0
None
[None, 3, 5, 7, 9]
1
None
[None, None, 5, 7, 9]
```

Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Comment: When I run the first code sample, I do not get any errors (after fixing the obvious indentation errors).  Are you sure this is the same code you ran?

Comment: I see no way one will get the error you reported. Are you sure this is the only code you have?

Comment: I do see one potential problem, although I don't see how it's relevant to the error: `m = [l,l]` does _not_ make two separate copies of `l`; it makes two _references_ to `l`, and since they are the same object, modifying one also modifies the other.

Comment: Agreed with @JohnGordon, I do not get any errors when running indentation-fixed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
l = [1,3,5,7,9]
m = [l[:],l[:]]
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if i != j:
            summ = l[i] + l[j]
            m[0][i] = summ
            m[1][j] = summ
print(m)
# [[10, 12, 14, 16, 16], [10, 12, 14, 16, 16]]
```

Make a shallow copy of `l` while declaring of `m`.